# Field Calculator Only Working for Beginning and End of Data Set

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm working with a dataset where every entry is a unique zip code in the United States (approx. 33,000 entries). I ran a simple field calculation:

```
def Rank(minrate):
    if minrate > .4: 
      return 'HiMin'
    else:
      return 'LoMin'
```

and it worked perfectly for all 33,000 entries. I'm running a very similar calculation:

```
def Rank(zip,state):
    if zip > state: 
      return 'HiLoan'
    else:
      return 'LoLoan'
```

[image: This is an example of the data. "zip" refers to the "loanpen" field and "state" refers to the "statepen" field. Both are long fields, with the LoanRank field being text.]

This is an example of the data. "zip" refers to the "loanpen" field and "state" refers to the "statepen" field. Both are double fields, with the LoanRank field being text. You can see AK working correctly above, with CA failing below. (A few natural nulls in the AK data that are correct).

And I'm running into an issue I've never seen before. The calculation appears to be working fine, if you look at Arizona, Arkansas, Alaska, Alabama, or start from the bottom and look at Wisconsin, Wyoming, and West Virginia... But for every other state in the middle (that doesn't start with A or W), the calculation is failing. It's not giving any error, just populating as Null.

I've tried doing a definition query on one of the failed states and running the code just on that state - still fails. I tried running the code on a single cell within one of the failed states - failed. I tried creating new columns, still fails.

I tend to think the issue is not with the Python, but something with ArcGIS.

If anyone else has experienced this, do you have an idea on what the issue might be or how to fix it?

[image]

Here's the data sorted by UID in the natural order, showing the null values do NOT break the code.

Comment: Are you comparing a numeric field (zip) with a text field (state) ? could you give us some exemple value (zip and state) that work and some that didn't work ?

Comment: I'm comparing two numeric values. I updated the post with an example.

Comment: Show how you call the function

Comment: U right, they're double. Doesn't change the issue tho. I'm calling it with Rank(Loan_Pen,State_Pen)

Comment: `Rank(!Loan_Pen!,!State_Pen!)`?

Comment: What do you want to happen when one value is `None`

Comment: Yes, I have the syntax correct, which is why it's working fine for the some of the states. When an input value is none, an output value of none is correct. As you can see with the CA examples, there are no none values but it's still failing.

Comment: Like i said, maybe the code stops executing at the first None. I can see you sorted the values accouring to STATE_NAME, so the order in your screenshot is not the actual table order.

Comment: Is Arkansas the first state where you have a Null value for Loan_Pen?

Comment: No, Alabama and Alaska also have null values. Likewise, Wyoming, WV, and Wisconsin have null values as well. There are also null values in the previous field I calculated, which had no issues.

Comment: your functions can only return non-null values, is the stuff running the function returning the null?   Other than that, they only think I can think of is that somehow the values don't have the same types

Answer (score 3):

You cant compare a number to `None` using ><

```
a = [[1,2], [3,None], [4,5]]

for x,y in a:
    if x<y:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Outputs:

```
yes
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Code will probably stop running at first `None` value. You can add a starting if statement, for example: `if not None in [x,y]:` or use try/except.

Comment: Nope, because a) as I mentioned, there are correct NULL values throughout the data, b) as I also mentioned, the process picks back up again once it get to the W states, and c) I tried adding a If None statement and it did nothing. Thanks though.